# Complete a dataset with information from another one

Tags: python, pandas

I created several datasets including different information that now I would like to merge.
An example of datasets (just two for simplicity) is the following:

```
Customer1       Customer2       Relationship   Age_of_Relationship
Alfa              Wolk               1                  12
Cyrius           Century             0                   1
Cyrius           Mercedes            0                  10
Apple            Microsoft           1                   4
Apple            Google              0                   3
Microsoft        Google              0                  12
```

and

```
All_Customers      Net      Recovered
Alfa             12412          1
Wolk             12435          0
Cyrius           14532          1
Century          12521          0
Mercedes         12353          0
Apple            15412          0
Microsoft        6412           1
Google           12146          1
```

I would like to add 2 columns, for each Customer (so for 1 and for 2), for each variable in the second dataset.

For example

```
Customer1       Customer2       Relationship   Age_of_Relationship    Net_Customer1  Net_Customer2    Recovered_1   Recovered_2
Alfa              Wolk               1                  12
Cyrius           Century             0                   1
Cyrius           Mercedes            0                  10
Apple            Microsoft           1                   4
Apple            Google              0                   3
Microsoft        Google              0                  12
```

with the corresponding values from the second dataset.
Can you please tell me how I can merge this info to complete the dataset with information on both Customer 1 and Customer 2 from a different dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a mapping from `df2` data for `df1` to lookup, by setting `All_Customers` as index with [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
mapping = df2.set_index('All_Customers')
```

Then, you can lookup the values of `Net` and `Recovered` from `df2` by `df1` keys `Customer1`, `Customer2`, by using [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as follows:

```
df1['Net_Customer1'] = df1['Customer1'].map(mapping['Net'])
df1['Net_Customer2'] = df1['Customer2'].map(mapping['Net'])
df1['Recovered_1'] = df1['Customer1'].map(mapping['Recovered'])
df1['Recovered_2'] = df1['Customer2'].map(mapping['Recovered'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

   Customer1  Customer2  Relationship  Age_of_Relationship  Net_Customer1  Net_Customer2  Recovered_1  Recovered_2
0       Alfa       Wolk             1                   12          12412          12435            1            0
1     Cyrius    Century             0                    1          14532          12521            1            0
2     Cyrius   Mercedes             0                   10          14532          12353            1            0
3      Apple  Microsoft             1                    4          15412           6412            0            1
4      Apple     Google             0                    3          15412          12146            0            1
5  Microsoft     Google             0                   12           6412          12146            1            1
```